# How to force minimum charge in Woocommerce, yet not restrict checkout?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm wondering how to force a minimum charge in Woocommerce, the e-commerce system for Wordpress. If the minimum is $100, and the items in the cart total only $23, the person can checkout, but they will be paying $100. This needs to reflect not only in the checkout, but also for the order invoice and any other relevant fields.

I'm okay with PHP, but I'm not familiar with the Woocommerce system. Logic-wise, I predict that we can mod the total calculator... if $total is >= 100 { proceed regularly } else { $total = 100 }. Or maybe dynamically add an item to the cart based on the difference between minimum charge and current cart total. I'm just concerned that I may mess things up by not putting in enough consideration as to how the entire site may need modding because that total amount shows up in many places.

NOTE: I am not talking about not letting people checkout if they don't meet a minimum order amount. There are plugins for that or I can use javascript to disable the checkout button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question:

To force this minimum charge, you have to tap into a couple of woocommerce parts. First is the ability to add an additional line (like a surcharge) to your total. Second is get the subtotal amount.

In your themes function.php, add this snippet ([original on Github](https://gist.github.com/corsonr/6182904) thanks [consonr at Github](https://gist.github.com/corsonr))

```
//ADD CUSTOM FEE
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

    global $woocommerce;

    $subt = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;

    if ($subt < 100 ) { 
        $surcharge = 100 - $subt;
    } else { 
        $surcharge = 0;
    }   

$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Surcharge', 'woocommerce'), $surcharge );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

My minimum charge is 100. The 100 has to be met as a subtotal, meaning before delivery fees. $woocommerce->cart->subtotal is where the subtotal amount is stored.

The above snippet will also add an additional line to your cart as well as in your checkout. The value of the "Surcharge" can be a fixed amount or you can make it a variable. In this case, I made it a variable ($surcharge). Since the snippet uses the subtotal variable, it is a dynamic change -- each time you update your cart, the surcharge will re-calculate.

The surcharge will be the minimum charge minus the subtotal. This will only happen when the subtotal is less than the minimum charge, otherwise we would end up with a negative surcharge.

In terms of followup design, you should also have a cart message to notify people of the surcharge. You could also consider using javascript to hide the surcharge part entirely if their subtotal meets the minimum charge.

**For woocommerce version 2.2.**